# Simple cyclic inequality, similar to Shapiro's

Tags: inequality

The numbers $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are poritive. Prove, that

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2} \leq \frac{3}{2}$$

Or show a counterexample. It looks simple, but I'm having a hard time proving / disproving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concrete counterexample is $x_1 = 1, x_3 = 2$, and let $x_2$ be very large. This works because we have
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} = \frac{1}{1+x_2} + \frac{x_2}{x_2+2} + \frac{2}{3} \approx \frac{5}{3}$$
when $x_2$ is very large.

The motivation for trying to find a counterexample (and a different, less concrete, solution) comes from the following: assume that $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \leq \frac{3}{2}$. Then,
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2} = 3 - \sum_{cyc} \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \geq \frac{3}{2} $$
However, this new inequality is the previous inequality with $x_2$ and $x_3$ swapped! This means that if we have some $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} < \frac{3}{2}$, then taking $(x_1,x_3,x_2)$ causes $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} > \frac{3}{2}$ for this new set of three values.